# How to Get Data from Specific Field in JSON Object Using Retrofit Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

i am currently trying to get data from specific field in JSON Object. The API is Github API and the feature i try to implement is search. The API results is looks like this

```
{
  "total_count": 70,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "login": "wirya",
      "id": 2296318,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIyOTYzMTg=",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/2296318?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/wirya",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/wirya",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wirya/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wirya/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wirya/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wirya/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wirya/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wirya/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wirya/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wirya/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wirya/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false,
      "score": 1.0
    },
    {
      "login": "wiryawan46",
      "id": 16128117,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE2MTI4MTE3",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/16128117?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/wiryawan46",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/wiryawan46",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wiryawan46/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wiryawan46/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wiryawan46/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wiryawan46/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wiryawan46/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wiryawan46/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wiryawan46/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wiryawan46/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/wiryawan46/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false,
      "score": 1.0
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get data from `"items"` field only. How can i do that using Retrofit in Kotlin language?

The code that i tried to use is like this:

```
@GET("search/users")
    suspend fun searchUsers(@Query("q") q: String): Response<List<User>>
```

It gives me error **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

Update: Here is my data class

```
data class User(

    var login: String,
    var type: String,
    var avatar_url: String,
    var public_repos: Int = 0,
    var followers: Int = 0,
    var following: Int = 0

)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please post your User class

Comment: Done sir, sorry too late because of different time zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match 'items' as a data class as well:

```
data class Items (
    val items: List<User>
)

data class User(
     var login: String,
     var type: String,
     var avatar_url: String,
     var public_repos: Int = 0,
     var followers: Int = 0,
     var following: Int = 0 
 )



@GET("search/users")
suspend fun searchUsers(@Query("q") q: String): Response<Items>
```

Comment: I tried this but when i try to set data for the adapters it gives me error because what i set in adapters is List<User> but the found data is Search(or in your answer case is Items). I am confused how to do that without change my adapter to much because it is has been configured for accept List<User> instead of Search/Items.

Comment: If you have any other code that&amp;#39;s affected then add it. Like the adapter

Comment: Im made change here and there and also i use Call instead of Response. It works. Thanks sir